# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Signal already used by VM or OS

Tags: java, macos, scala, intellij-idea

I'm working with some Java that is trying to handle the "URG" signal like so:

`Signal.handle(new Signal("URG"), handler)`

However, I keep receiving `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Signal already used by VM or OS: SIGURG` on my `macOs Catalina 10.15.5` system with  AdoptOpen JDK Version: `12.0.1.j9-adpt` JVM.

I've stepped through the code with a debugger and I don't see this signal being added ahead of time and Google is turning up 0 results.

---

OK, I made a minimal reproduction in Scala:

```
import sun.misc.{Signal, SignalHandler}

object Main extends App {
  Signal.handle(new Signal("URG"),  URGHandler.handle)
  println("hello")
}

object URGHandler extends SignalHandler {
  override def handle(sig: Signal): Unit = {
    print("received signal")
  }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Signal already used by VM or OS: SIGURG
    at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Signal.handle(Signal.java:173)
```

Here is the command Intellij is running to run the program:

```
 ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/12.0.1.j9-adpt/bin/java \
 -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53899:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin \
 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
 -classpath /Users/userperson/IdeaProjects/urg/target/scala-2.13/classes:/Users/userperson/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.4/scala-library-2.13.4. jar \
 Main
```

---

And a minimal reproduction in Java:

```
import sun.misc.Signal;
import sun.misc.SignalHandler;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Signal.handle(new Signal("URG"),  new URGHandler());
    }
}

class URGHandler implements SignalHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(Signal sig) {
        System.out.println("hello signal");
    }
}
```

Other signals I have tried:

- URG: fail
- USR1: fail
- USR2: fail
- TERM: success

Comment: Note that the error message says, 'used by VM _or_ OS'. Stepping through Java code with a debugger won't show you either of these. SIGURG is a rather exotic item; are you sure that it is relevant to your application? A little bit of Googling didn't show me any positive evidence that it is is ever delivered on MacOS.

Comment: I just tried this, and that line of code works fine for me as the only thing in `main()` and an empty SignalHandler subclass defined and instantiated to accept the signal notification.  I'm running MacOS 10.15.7, openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14 LTS, and IntelliJ 2020.2.3.   I also tried it with openjdk 14.0.2 2020-07-14 - as for chaining, I think you need to be more specific about your needs, and that topic ought to be moved to a separate question.

Comment: Should have gone with the simpler example myself. It works for me as well. The mystery remains. CTR + F ing through the project I can't find anywhere that adds the signal before this. I'll have to ask around.

Comment: I might have thought to say the same thing, but now the OP is saying in the question's comments that executing just the line where the error occurs does not reproduce the error.  Something else in his code is somehow contributing to the problem.  It is, of course, quite possible for the execution of a line of Java code to influence the behavior of the VM or OS, and that seems to be at least peripherally the case here.

Comment: I'm kind of a Scala novice so when I wrote my example yesterday I wrote my main method incorrectly. I've added a minimal example in Scala that does reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK turns out all that Signal Chaining documentation on Google didn't work, but changing the JDK to Oracle Open JDK 15.0.1 did.